# Should we start merging duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-management, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms

I noticed while scrolling through the list of existing tags that `weight`, `weight-loss`, `body-weight`, `overweight`, and `weight-gain` all exist as separate tags, as do `food-poisoning`, `foodborneillness`, and `food-safety`; `diagnostics`, `diagnosis` and `differential-diagnosis`; `allergy` and `allergies`; `medication` and `medications`; and so on.

We're still a beta site, so I can understand how easy tag creation would result in all these duplicate tags, but in a field like health where so many people have such specific specialties, duplicate tags make it hard for the right questions to reach the right people. As, say, a psychiatrist, I'd need to know to look for questions with the tags `psychology-psychology`, `psychiatrist-psychiatry` and `mental-health`,  which isn't too bad. A weight loss specialist on the other hand, as shown above, would be in for a surprise.

What can we do about this, and to what degree should we be stepping in?

**Note:** I was choosing tags for this post, and noticed `tag-management`, `tagging` and `tags` all as separate tags, so I did the only sensible thing and went with them all.

Answer (score 3):

When you have 1,250 rep you'll be able to suggest tag synonyms. In the meantime, I think it's appropriate to proceed with most of these merges. The community just needs to decide which ones should be the "parent" tags. I would propose (`A` > `B`  = merge `A` into `B` and remap new tags called `A` to `B`):

- `weight` > `body-weight`
- `foodborneillness` > `food-poisoning`
- `allergy` > `allergies`
- `medication` > `medications`

The rest of those seem sufficiently differentiated to warrant separate tags to me, but I'm not firmly committed to any of this.

Comment: I'd suggest merging 'broken-bones' with 'bone-fractures' (I don't have a score >5 in this one)